# IntelliJ idea not starting in Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

In My Mac: `10.11.4 (15E65)`, My IntelliJ Idea: `2017.1.3`, which was working perfectly earlier, suddenly stopped working. I have restarted the Mac with clearing RAM multiple times. It just get stuck with this Window and goes in "Not Responding" state:

[image]

Comment: Try to move/clear directory of IDE [Configuration and Caches](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)

Comment: Can I delete the whole directory: ~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
 ?

Comment: @Andrey After clearing cache and configuration, it opens, but when I open project it again goes on a ride.

Comment: What is the project type? You can also [Submit a support request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) with complete [IDE log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) folder zipped after issue happens. We will check the issue.